# there is no question of . .

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

The noun "question" has two meanings: "doubt" and "possibility."

I'd like to know when "There is no question of . . ." has one meaning but not the other.

Comment: I think any distinction would be artificial. If you are claiming that there is no possibility of something, then the question of whether it was possible must have been raised.

Comment: Without context, is "There is no question of his returning" ambiguous?